# Why execution time of one sub-thread is more than that of the whole application

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance

This is a multithreaded application, in one of the subthreads I wrote below code to calculate the execution time of the thread run function:

```
       class CThreadObject{
           public:
                ...
                unsigned long GetTime(){
                   struct timeval val;
                   gettimeofday(&val, NULL);
                   return (val.tv_sec * 1000000 + val.tv_usec);
                }

                static void* Run(void *param){ // thread function
                    while (1){
                          static unsigned long ExecTime = GetTime();
                          unsigned long LastExecTime = 0;

                          if (TurnOnTest()){
                              LastExecTime = ExecTime;
                              ExecTime = GetTime();
                             mQueue.push_back(ExecTime - LastExecTime);                     
                              //std::deque<unsigned long> mQueue
                          }

                          //some other jobs such as 
                          //I/O demultiplex and events dispatching
                          .......
                    };

                    return NULL;
                }  

                void PrintStatistics(){
                    unsigned long tmp = 0;
                    while(mQueue.size()){
                          tmp += *mQueue.begin();
                          mQueue.pop_front();
                    }

                    printf("the total time is %lu\n", tmp);
                }

           private:
                ...
                std::deque<unsigned long> mQueue;
                pthread_t  mThread;
       };
```

The application performs only 1 minutes, but I found that time accumulated by 
all elements of gQueue is 175 seconds which is larger than time of the whole application. 
Why would this happen?

**[UPDATE]**
Added one more function -- PrintStatistics()

Comment: Not an answer, but I advise you to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` when making these kinds of time measurements. `gettimeofday()` is affected by the system time, which can change while your app is running (DST, NTP, etc.)

Comment: When you say "I found that time accumulated by all elements of qQueue is 175 seconds" what do you mean by this? Are you adding all of the members of gQueue together? If so, that would be wrong since the threads are running concurrently and each individual thread could run for the length of the program. Please post the contents of gQueue at the end of your application run to help us understand your question.

Comment: You seem to be initializing `LastTime` to 0 on every loop iteration...

Comment: @Nathanael Yes, I added all the members of mQueue together. By saying " each individual thread could run for the length of the program", do you mean if the program takes X minutes, then if we added all execution time of sub-threads together, say it's Y mintues, and this Y may be much larger than X?

Comment: @StevePeng - Yes I do mean this. See CosmicComputer's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your threads are not measuring their runtime; they are measuring the difference (roughly) between their start time and their end time.  During that time, they are not constantly running; as there are multiple threads (and multiple processes on your machine), they are sharing processor time, so some of the time in the interval between start and finish is spent idle.

Imagine the following: two people go into work at 9 AM.  They take turns performing some task - driving a forklift, for example - and continue to switch off, alternating between doing the task and taking breaks, until 5 PM, at which point they clock out.  Together, they have logged 16 hours of work, but the forklift was operating for only 8, and the workday (here, your program's run time) was only 8 hours long.  Your program is measuring the time in - time out difference.

Comment: but if the application runs for X minutes, then the execution time of each thread must be no more than X minutes, needn't it?

Comment: @StevePeng - correct, but if you have N threads running then the sum of the execution times for all threads may be as high as N*X minutes, even if the application finishes in less than X minutes...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that on a multi-processor machine the threads could actually be running concurrently. To develop your analogy, we could have any number of workers sharing a number of forklifts between them.